# VBA send email with specific column

Tags: vba, excel

i have a excel list and and i want to make a button to send an email in the list using template, the target email address is in column K, but i only want to send it if column A is showing YES.

I wrote a script to loop every row i want and see if column A has "YES" or not, if yes then refer to another macro.

but i got stuck in anther macro, i cant specify .to = column K

Here is the loop script to find if column A has YES:

```
sub agreement2 ()
dim startrow as integer
startrow = 9
dim mylastrow3 as integer
lastrow3 = activesheet.cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row
dim i as integer

for i = 9 to lastrow3
if (cells(i, 1).value = "YES") then
send_letter
end if
end sub
```

Here is my send_letter script

```
Sub send_letter()

Dim Subject
Dim Body
Dim otlapp As Object
Dim olMail2 As Object
Dim ws As Object


Set otlapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMail2 = otlapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\cpadm001.corp.ocalwa.com\clk\DEPT\CLKDEPT6\IMT\SAO\SSC\Team\Team1\New Joiner Script\agreement.oft")
Set doc2 = olMail2.GetInspector.WordEditor
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Send Letters")

vTemplateBody2 = olMail2.HTMLBody
Subject2 = "Agreement Letter"
HTMLBody2 = vTemplateBody2


With olMail2
.To = ????????????????.Value
.Subject = Subject2
Set WrdRng = doc2.Range
WrdRng.Paste
.Send

End With

 End Sub
```

Could anyone help with the column K thing. thank you so much.

Comment: Change `send_letter` to `send_letter(r)` and alter call: `send_letter i`. Your code will be: `.To = Cells(r, "K").Value`

Comment: Thanks, its works.....

Comment: I will promote it to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `send_letter` to `send_letter(r)`
2. Alter call from `send_letter` to `send_letter i`
3. Your final code will be: `.To = Cells(r, "K").Value`